# How can I convert my JSON into the format required to make a D3 sunburst diagram?

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
    "data": {
        "databis": {
            "dataexit": {
                "databis2": {
                    "1250": { }
                }
            },
            "datanode": {
                "20544": { }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use it to generate a [D3 sunburst diagram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423), but that requires a [different data format](https://github.com/defunctzombie/d3-examples/blob/master/dendrogram/flare.json):

```
{
    "name": "data",
    "children": [ 
        {
            "name": "databis",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "dataexit",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "databis2",
                            "size": "1250"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "datanode",
                    "size": "20544"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do this with Python? I think I need to use a recursive function, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: The thing you want is neither valid JSON nor valid Python.

Comment: Please show your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Possible dupe: [How to update a JSON file by using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24579896/2415822)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursive solution with function that takes name and dictionary as parameter. For every item in given `dict` it calls itself again to generate list of children which look like this: `{'name': 'name here', 'children': []}`.

Then it will check for special case where there's only one child which has key `children` with value of empty list. In that case `dict` which has given parameter as a name and child name as size is returned. In all other cases function returns `dict` with name and children.

```
import json

data = {
    "data": {
        "databis": {
            "dataexit": {
                "databis2": {
                    "1250": { }
                }
            },
            "datanode": {
                "20544": { }
            }
        }
    }
}

def helper(name, d):
    # Collect all children
    children = [helper(*x) for x in d.items()]

    # Return dict containing size in case only child looks like this:
    # {'name': '1250', 'children': []}
    # Note that get is used to so that cases where child already has size
    # instead of children work correctly
    if len(children) == 1 and children[0].get('children') == []:
        return {'name': name, 'size': children[0]['name']}

    # Normal case where returned dict has children
    return {'name': name, 'children': [helper(*x) for x in d.items()]}

def transform(d):
    return helper(*next(iter(d.items())))

print(json.dumps(transform(data), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "name": "data",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "databis",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "dataexit",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "databis2",
                            "size": "1250"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "datanode",
                    "size": "20544"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: A Thousand Thanks Bro :D /D it works.  really amazing.