# Modify JSON data in Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to amend the value of a node in my JSON, however, I keep getting "SyntaxError: invalid Syntax"

Every question I've looked at gives the same answer: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21035861/2029983), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13949837/2029983), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24579926/2029983). As do online article ([example](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-update-a-json-file-in-python)). Use (in psuedo terms) `{jsonvariable}.["{Node Name}"] = {new value}` however, this doesn't work, no matter what I try, the Python file refuses to run.

This makes me assume it's my implementation, but perhaps it bceause these answers are based on Python 2 and I'm (currently) using 3.7.5.

The JSON value I'm trying to update is a second level value, which might make a difference, however, Googling/Searching appears to never bring me to a example with that, and I know that `clock.[id+".Status"] = "Finished` doesn't work.

The JSON snippet looks like this:

```
{
    "0c2ad7d1-0fc9-47d5-99a2-2e7c8cff2a3d": {
        "Status": "Finished",
        "Status Time": "2020-05-17 16:48:12.584676",
        "Channel ID": 704635364039589941,
        "Active Player": 1,
        "Message ID": "",
        "Player1": {
            "Name": "Larnu",
            "ID": 357506009675333632,
            "Remaining": "01:00"
        },
        "Player2": {
            "Name": "Dolphin Bot",
            "ID": 357506009675333632,
            "Remaining": "01:00"
        }
    },
    "a370d674-6f1a-41be-86d2-9f8c73ab8ab0": {
        "Status": "Not Started",
        "Status Time": "2020-05-17 16:48:12.584676",
        "Channel ID": 704635364039589941,
        "Active Player": "1",
        "Message ID": "711605974779166730",
        "Player1": {
            "Name": "Larnu",
            "ID": 357506009675333632,
            "Remaining": "01:00:00"
        },
        "Player2": {
            "Name": "Dolphin Alpha",
            "ID": 704635572580253818,
            "Remaining": "01:00:00"
        }
    }
}
```

And the value I'm trying to change is `Status` in the `a370d674-6f1a-41be-86d2-9f8c73ab8ab0` truee. The relevant part that's erroring is:

```
                with open("clocks.json","r+") as clocks_file:
                    clocks = json.load(clocks_file)
                    clock = clocks[clockid]
                    clock.['Status'] = "Finished"
```

`clockid` *would* have been set previously (if the Python file ran) with the value `a370d674-6f1a-41be-86d2-9f8c73ab8ab0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you'll want to get rid of the `.` before the `[`. In other words:

```
clock['Status'] = 'Finished'
```

or, without assignment:

```
clocks[clockid]['Status'] = 'Finished'
```

Comment: `clocks[clockid]['Status'] ` is exactly what I need here. Didn't realise it was that simple.

Comment: Had to take the solution off. Doing this is malforming the JSON file. It's adding additional Braces `}` at the end.

Comment: OK, seems like using `r+` does it. using `w` is fine. Weird... Why would `r+` and `w` operate differently for write command...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use . before []. Try:

```
clock['Status'] = "Finished"
```