# Writing multiple lines of python code in a single line in shell script

Tags: python, json, shell

I'm trying to edit a json file using shell scripts without using jq. I found the necessary python code to do so, [Python read JSON file and modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035762/python-read-json-file-and-modify), but when I try to execute all of it in a single line in shell, I receive a syntax error.
I wrote the following command:

```
export data = `python -c "import json;import os;filename='test.json';with open(filename, 'r') as f:data = json.load(f) data['id'] = 'abc';os.remove(filename);with open(filename, 'w') as f:json.dump(data, f, indent=4)"`
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you just put your code in a separate python script which you can call with a single line in shell? python yourscript.py. You can also have your script take any arguments you would need.

Comment: Why not just make a `.py` file and run that?

Comment: i'm trying to run a jenkins job through shell and I need one of the jenkins parameters which will be used to modify the data in the json. That's why I need to perform the modify operation in a single command.

Comment: Make sure you do not have spaces around `=`. Also consider `$()` replacing the backticks, resulting in `export data=$(python ...)`

Comment: I tried to execute:
       
export data=(python -c "import json;import os;filename='test.json';with open(filename, 'r') as f:data = json.load(f) data['id'] = 'abc';os.remove(filename);with open(filename, 'w') as f:json.dump(data, f, indent=4)")

.I see a syntax error at 'with'.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:

```
$(python -c "import json;import os;filename='test.json';f=open(filename, 'r');data=json.load(f);data['id']="abc";os.remove(filename);f=open(filename, 'w');json.dump(data, f, indent=4);")
```

Thanks anyway!