# Delete specific data in json Discord.py

Tags: json, discord.py

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def example(ctx, key):
    with open('amounts.json') as f:
     amounts = json.load(f)
    if key in amounts:

       if amounts[key] > int(99):
        await ctx.send("Success")
        (DELETE IT HERE)

        _save()
        member = ctx.message.author
        this_guild = member.guild

        role = get(member.guild.roles, name='Test')
        await member.add_roles(role)
        Message = ctx.message
        await Message.delete()

       else:
         await ctx.send("Invalid!")

    else:
        await ctx.send("Invalid!")
```

So I was making something and I need to delete a specific thing in json example:

```
{"172046029078659072": 78, "201941438": 78, "444591956": 78, "221448711": 100, "937709987": 100}
```

So say I want to delete " "201941438": 78 " out of that file how would I do that in discord.py?

Comment: You need to modify `amounts` and then use `json.dump` to write the dictionary to the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python read JSON file and modify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035762/python-read-json-file-and-modify)

Comment: It removes everything but I only want to remove  "201941438": 78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the key with `del amounts["201941438"]` where `"201941438"` is your key. Then save (`dump`) the json file back to disk.